# Button not being detected when pressed?

Tags: swift

This is my current code:

```
import UIKit
import LocalAuthentication



class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func sendHelp(sender: UIButton){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "It worked", message: "yey", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

It doesn't detect when the button is pressed. I can't use the segues (control+drag) in my code, so this could be an issue with Xcode. What should I do?

Comment: Is this actually your full code? Where is the viewDidLoad? Without this your ViewController isn’t loaded *_____”

Comment: Please make a new action: Select the storyboard, press ⌥⌘↩ to open the Assistant Editor, ⌃-drag from the button into the associated view controller, in the popup select `IBAction` and sender `UIButton` and press ↩. Note the difference of the method signature.

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of important details.

Comment: To all the answers above: I will do these when I can get back home. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't control-drag from the storyboard typically you have not set the class of the viewcontroller correctly - select the view in the storyboard and then set the class as "viewcontroller".

Also make sure that it is properly linked to the button.

[image]